# Lauching Lotus Notes with mailto:

Tags: url, lotus-notes

I have a mailto url in a web page. The target system contains both Microsoft Outlook and Lotus Notes. Microsoft Outlook is the **default** Mail Client. So when i click on *mailto* link it opens up Microsoft Outlook.

I want it to open Lotus Notes when i click on the link and i do **NOT** want change the default mail client settings in Internet Options as well. Please suggest a solution or work around to achive this.

Comment: afaik, this is not possible. You have no control over the clients computer. The only thing you could do use some sort of plugin which facilitates your request.

Comment: Thanks for you response lkke, please elaborate on the plugin thing you are referring to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a notes:// style URL, which will work for users with recent versions of the Notes client installed. This URL format can be used to launch a database (or open a known document in a database) whose file path is known. Unfortunately, for creating an email document in the current user's mailbox, the NSF path will be different for each user. But there is a technique you can use, if you have a Notes server in your environment. You can have the link on your page actually link to a static Notes database, which has an "OnDatabaseOpen" event handler set up to look up the user's mailbox path, and then redirect the user there. It's a few steps - not as simple as a mailto: URL - but if you are desperate, it can be made to work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this URL to open Notes and a new memo: `Notes:///0000000000000E00/Memo?OpenForm`

source: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/notes-urls

This however does not solve the problem of filling out the To address, Subject, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A mailto link is always going to use the default mail app.  You may be able to use a lotus notes shortcut and pass the email address as arguments.

Comment: What i'm looking for is yahoo messenger type url 
ymsgr:sendim?notarealuser&m=This+is+my+message for Lotus Notes.